# Project xxx is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Project xxx supports: net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have ASP .net core project that reference some .net framework libraries. We want to upgrade from .net framework 4.6 to 4.8. After upgrade I've got error Package xxx is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2. This package is referencing Newtonsoft.Json from nuget.

I found that the problem is somehow related to reference to Newtonsoft.Json. Without this reference it build fine. I can reproduce the same error just by these steps:

1. create empty ASP .net core project
2. create .net framework class library
3. reference #2 from #1
   (it still build fine)
4. add reference to Newtonsoft.Json to #2 
   I get error Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Project ClassLibrary1 supports: net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2)

When I change framework version to 4.6 it builds fine.

Comment: does Newtonsoft.Json support 4.8 and standard at the time of this writing?

Comment: fyi this is an outstanding issue - they want .net core and .net 5 to be restore-compatible with all versions of .net framework - currently it is 4.6.1. But: If you create a library project to use in .net core and .net framework, you should create a .NET Standard class library instead.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to csproj file of web application and it resolved the issue:

$(AssetTargetFallback);net48;net461

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this the right way to add the AssetTargetFallback? Please suggest. Because I am still getting the same error.

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
      <AssetTargetFallback Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.2'">
        $(AssetTargetFallback);net48;net461
      </AssetTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
```